# R Loops to run through 100 different identical excel files, create bargraph and export to a folder

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, data-manipulation

I am not entirely sure how to create a reproducible example for my question.

I am new to using loops and would love some advice. My task is to create barcharts for 100 different hospitals using 100 different Excel sheets (that have the exact same format) and export each barchart into a folder by having the hospital's ID for each picture.

Currently, the code I have allows me to do this, but I have to manually go in and change the hospital name and then run the code and it will export the bargraph. However, I am trying to create a loop so when I make a list of all the hospitals it will automatically just loop through and create the 100 bargraphs.

I would change OHT_list and OHT_ for each hospital here and then run the second portion of the code and it would create the bargraphs. Here is my code:

```
# Define my list 
OHT_list <- c("Hospital 1")  #I would need to change this for each hospital and run the below code
OHT_ <- c("H1") ##I would need to change this for each hospital and run the below code
SegmentType <- "Segment A" #can be segment A/B/C
Indicator <- "Indicator A"  
Years <- "2022/23"
```

This is the code which creates the bargraphs and exports it to the file.path

```
if (SegmentType == "Segment A" || SegmentType == "Segment B" || SegmentType=="Segment C") {
  combined_data <- list()
  
  # Find Folder Names to access based on OHT_list elements (numeric values)
  for (OHT in OHT_list) {
    
    ending <- sub(".*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", OHT)
    
    file_name <- paste0("SegmentationResults_", SegmentType, "_", ending, ".xlsx")
    file_path <- file.path("C:\downloads", OHT, file_name)

  
   data <- read_excel(file_path, sheet = "xx")
  
  # Filter out "all" row and save relevant years
  filtered_data <- all_data %>%
    filter(`Reporting Period` == Years & `Segment Label` != "")

  # Colors
  colors_sequence <- c("#0A1A31", "#C7EA95", "#2E80BC", "#EE654F", "#7BB4A9")
  color_map <- rep(colors_sequence, length.out = length(unique(filtered_data$OHT)))
  names(color_map) <- unique(filtered_data$OHT)

  file_name <- paste0("fig_", SegmentType, "_", ending, ".png")
  file_path <- file.path ("C:/downloads/IndicatorA", file_name)
  
  png(file_path, width = 1400, height = 900)

  plot <- filtered_data %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = yy, y = `xx`)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#0A1A31")+
    scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .10)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c())+
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 35) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom", legend.spacing.y = unit(-0.5, "cm"), legend.text = element_text(size=25))
  
  plot
    
}

  dev.off()
```

Comment: This is what functions are made for! Wrap all that code into a function, and then use e.g. `lapply(your_hospitals, your_function)`. E.g. have a look at this book chapter: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html

Comment: Creating a table with the name of the hospital, ids, segments, indicators, and dates would be a good practice. Then you can use that table as input to your function, and with Axeman's advice you'll have a functional loop. Another benefit of that table is that you'll document your input data in a readable and accessible format.